# Is rogue used as a good adjective or bad adjective?

Tags: vocabulary, adjectives

I am a software engineer and one of the team of developers in my company has a name - "Rogue one". They have decided by themselves. My question is why "Rogue one". As per my understanding Rogue means - "destructive", doing things in an unmannered way. Something which is actually bad. Is my understanding correct of the word Rogue?

Comment: Sure it's not a reference to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_One?

Answer (score 3):

[**Rogue**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rogue) has the following two common meanings according to The Free Dictionary:

> 1. An unprincipled, deceitful, and unreliable person; a scoundrel or rascal.
> 2. One who is playfully mischievous; a scamp.

The negative connotation of rogue is the first one, but the second one is a playful or naughty reference ("*She laughingly exclaimed 'Oh, you rogue!'*").

That said, given the name is **Rogue One**, are you sure they're not fans of Star Wars/sci-fi, and are referencing the movie in the Star Wars franchise titled [**Rogue One**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_One)?

Comment: Good answer.  There is also a third usage.  Some non-conformists take the first meaning as a badge of honor.